# Adding Meta Tags to Files and Folders in Windows XP

Tags: windows, tagging, utilities

Is there any softwares available in Windows XP for adding meta tags to files and folders. i am looking for a tools similar to Tags/Punakea in Mac OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about [TaggedFrog](http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/tag-files-windows/)?